# Заставить правильно работать Gulp+browserify+external

Tags: javascript, gulp

Есть у меня такой код `app.js`

```
import Backbone from 'backbone';
import User from './models/user';
import Promise from 'bluebird';
// некоторый код
```

И такой `gulp.js`

```
var gulp           = require("gulp"),
    browserify     = require('browserify'),
    buffer         = require('vinyl-buffer'),
    source         = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    babelify       = require("babelify");

gulp.task('js', function () {

    var b = browserify({
        entries: './src/app.js',
        debug: false
    });

    return b
        .transform(babelify)
        .external('bluebird')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

`bluebird` у меня загружается отдельно и имеет глобальную переменную `Promise`, соответственно я не хочу его упаковывать. Как заставить `browserify` правильно это всё отработать?

Сейчас у меня получается нерабочий код

```
var Promise = _interopRequire(require("bluebird"));
// ...
{"bluebird":"bluebird"}
```

т.е. просто ссылается на строку, а должно быть

```
{"bluebird": function(require,module,exports){
    module.exports = Promise;
}
```

в `webpack` я знаю это делается очень легко

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    //...
    externals: {
        'bluebird': 'Promise'
    },
    //...
};
```

А как провернуть такой трюк в Gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы использовать глобальный объект `Promise` через `require` вам нужно использовать плагин [*browserify-shim*](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim). Он конфигурируется через `package.json` и вам нужно добавить туда следующие строчки:

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": ["browserify-shim"]
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "bluebird": "global:Promise",
}
```

При этом, подключение bluebird в коде не будет отличаться от подключения любой другой библиотеки:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
```

либо, для ES6:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';
```

**UPD:**

Мой `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp           = require("gulp"),
    browserify     = require('browserify'),
    buffer         = require('vinyl-buffer'),
    source         = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    babelify       = require("babelify");

gulp.task('default', function () {

    var b = browserify({
        entries: './app.js',
        debug: false
    });

    return b
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Подключение библиотек в HTML файле имеет вид:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/latest/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Файл `app.js`, который использовался для тестов имеет вид:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';

var getPromise = function(data) {
    return (new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(data);
    }));
}

// Можно убедиться, что Promise работает.
getPromise('test').then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

// Стандартная реализация Promise в браузере не имеет метода noConflict.
console.log(Promise.noConflict);
```

Comment: да, я пробовал так делать. но не работает.
результат от этого не меняется.


видимо, проблема именно в том, что подключение идёт через
`import Promise from 'bluebird';`, а не через require

Comment: @j.Doe, я провел несколько тестов. Этот подход работает для `import`. Похоже, что-то у вас в коде не так. Как вы определяете, что Bluebird не подключен?

Comment: странно. могли бы показать, как делали вы?
У меня получается тот код, который я показал в вопросе. У меня не происходит нормальное подключение

Comment: @j.Doe, обновил ответ

Comment: да, выглядит правильным.
у меня он почему-то тянет исходник птицы прямо в пакет, поэтому использую external.
А если bluebird установлен локально через тот же npm?

Comment: @j.Doe Не только выглядит, но еще и работает ;)

Comment: нашёл почему у меня этот вариант не работает. оказалось, что 
webpack умеет определять эти переменные глобально, т.е. для моего кода и всех зависимостей. а browserify нет, ему каждой зависимости нужно прописывать в package.json такой конфиг. а у меня как раз в одной из зависимостей используется bluebird.
теперь другая проблема, как сделать так, чтобы всё работало, но при этом не трогать чужие package.json?
смотрел на параметр
`browserify({
 globalTransform: babelify
})`
но ничего не произошло

Comment: @j.Doe, я понятия не имею при чем тут webpack и как он вообще связан с изначальной проблемой, описанной в вопросе

Comment: в вопросе я просто привёл пример, как это делается в вебпаке, поэтому и упомянул о нём сейчас

Comment: @j.Doe, ок, тогда о каких package.json файлах идет речь? Вы собираете проект с использованием gulp + browserify только в _одном месте_. А раз так, то и package.json должен настраиваться только один раз для этого проекта. Что-то не то вы пытаетесь сделать....

Comment: нашёл вот такую настройку `.transform(babelify, {"global":"true", "compact":"false"})`, но он тогда пакует вообще всё без разбора.
у меня через Import подключается библиотека лежащая в папке node_modules. Саму библиотеку мне запакавать нужно, а её зависимости - нет. Я могу, конечно, отредактировать package.json этой  библиотеки, но это сойдёт только в качестве временного решения

Comment: @j.Doe, Еще раз. Вы изменяете `package.json` только для самого проекта(того, что вы собираете). Все его зависимости **автоматически** будут (должны) использовать глобальную переменную `Promise` вместо пакета `bluebird`.

Comment: для каждого пакета свой конфиг (package.json), собирая свой проект, я лезу (Import) в папку `node_modules/some_plagin`, чтобы подключить оттуда библиотеку. На неё не распространяются мои настройки, т.к. там свой файл package.json, даже babelify не подхватывает её без выставления параметра "global". Сейчас я добавил настройки shim в package.json этой библиотеку и всё заработало, но нужно что-то более правильное.
условно считайте, что мне нужно из двух проектов собрать один, но при этом у них есть общие зависимости, которые я не хочу грузить дважды

Comment: ладно, это уже отдельный вопрос. в целом ведь, ответ верный